# On Arduino Micro what pin is used to flash led on boot

Tags: arduino

On the Uno one can wire a led to pin 13 which makes the led flash on startup.

Which pin number is this on the Micro?

Comment: According to `https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-micro` it should be digital pin 13 as you said.

Comment: However there is `LED_BUILTIN` so it'll work even with variants with LED on different digital pin.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @eyllanesc Oops, I'm sorry. You're absolutely right!

Comment: @Stan If you know that it is the wrong place, why do you mark an answer as correct, because if the question is inaccurate then the answers will be too?

Comment: Usually, yes. But in this case the answer was indeed correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pin 13 as the internet says. https://images.app.goo.gl/4U22RQ88RsSHqGKb9

Comment: In SO we answer only questions about programming, in Stack Exchange there are other sites for this type of questions like https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ so it is recommended that you avoid answering these types of questions